# MaaS DHCP issue on 14.04

Tags: networking, maas

I'm having an issue with 14.04LTS server via MAAS installation (on a VM).  iscsi does not connect after the PXE netboot:

```
iscsistart: Logging into iqn.2004-05.com.ubuntu:maas:ephemeral-ubuntu-amd64-generic-trusty-release 172.17.172.1:3260,1

iscsistart: can not connect to iSCSI daemon (111)!
```

I think the issue is that the DHCP client in the PXE booted image (also 14.04 LTS amd) is asking for an IP address that doesn't sit on the same subnet as the one we're running. From `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May 11 08:17:43 172 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:0c:29:b2:97:a2 via eth1
May 11 08:17:44 172 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.17.172.103 to 00:0c:29:b2:97:a2 via eth1
May 11 08:17:45 172 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 172.17.172.103 (172.17.172.1) from 00:0c:29:b2:97:a2 via eth1
May 11 08:17:45 172 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 172.17.172.103 to 00:0c:29:b2:97:a2 via eth1
May 11 08:18:06 172 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:0c:29:b2:97:a2 via eth1
May 11 08:18:06 172 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.17.172.103 to 00:0c:29:b2:97:a2 (maas-enlist) via eth1
May 11 08:18:06 172 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.137.131 (192.168.137.254) from 00:0c:29:b2:97:a2 via eth1: ignored (not authoritative).
```

The first discover-offer-request-ack is from the PXE netboot. The second one, discover-offer-request-ignore is from the image that was booted. The 192.168.137.131 makes no sense. I don't think it came from any configuration setting I have.

#### WORKAROUND

worked: I deleted the predefined clusters and networks, and added a single managed network using 192.168.137.* with the region and cluster controller on 192.168.137.10.  I don't really care about the IP addresses on the subnet, so this works, but it was confusing.  192.168.137.1 didn't work as the controller IP either, that seemed to cause the TFTP problem.